# SAS Conditional Statement

Tags: sas

This:

```
IF VAR1 ne VAR2 ne VAR3 ne VAR4;
```

I want this condition to check if:

- VAR1 is not equal to VAR2, VAR3, VAR4
- VAR2 is not equal to VAR1, VAR3, VAR4
- VAR3 is not equal to VAR1, VAR2, VAR4
- VAR4 is not equal to VAR2, VAR3, VAR1

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know SAS, but if you mean none equal to any other then that's only six comparisons and you can just 'and' them all I'd expect?

Comment: `VAR1 ne VAR2 and VAR1 ne VAR3 and VAR1 ne VAR4 and VAR2 ne VAR3 and VAR2 ne VAR4 and VAR3 ne VAR4` - surely there must be a way of collapsing this?

Comment: Yeah, that should work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options. Do it in long-form with `and` between:

```
VAR1 ne VAR2 and VAR1 ne VAR3 and VAR1 ne VAR4 and 
VAR2 ne VAR3 and VAR2 ne VAR4 and VAR3 ne VAR4
```

Or use the numerical equivalent of a TRUE value as 1 to test it:

```
sum(VAR1 = VAR2,
VAR1 = VAR3,
VAR1 = VAR4,
VAR2 = VAR3,
VAR2 = VAR4,
VAR3 = VAR4) = 0
```

Answer (score 5):

I think for the four variable case the six anded IFs is probably best.  However, if you want to do this unbounded, an array solution is evident; it's more work here than needed but is less work than 10 variables -> 45 ifs.

```
data want;
  set have;
  match=0;
  array vars var:;
  do _t = 1 to dim(vars)-1;
    do _u = _t+1 to dim(vars);
      if vars[_t] = vars[_u] then match=1;
    end;
    if match=1 then leave;
  end;
run;
```

This does the same thing as the 6 if's (tests 1 vs 2,3,4, tests 2 vs 3,4, tests 3 vs 4), but in array/loop form.

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
if var1=var2=var3=var4 then ...
```

There's some limitations to this but I can't recall them at the moment. In a straight IF condition I think it's okay.

Comment: The negation of this expression is true in cases that the asker doesn't want, e.g. `a=b=c!=d`.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively:

```
if var1 ^in (var2 var3 var4) and
if var2 ^in (var3 var4) and
if var3 ^in (var4);
```

- Or "not in".

Comment: That syntax is very hard to read, and is more work than other solutions.  `^in` is not something I'd expect to see in a SAS program, for good reason.

Comment: Please do elaborate? I believe the in operator is defined as being used to compare one value to a list of values. Happy to be corrected, though.

Comment: `^in` works, but it's not very easy to read.  In general I dislike `^` in SAS - using `not in` is much easier to read and to see what's going on.  On the other hand, I'm not sure why we need four in statements - you're making 12 comparisons instead of six.

Comment: @Joe so ne is better than ^= ?

Comment: Absolutely. It is of course partly personal style, but ne is much easier to read. Carets are very small characters, so I strongly discourage their use as they can be easy to miss when scanning through code.

Comment: I think it's hard to say absolutely to a style question. Personally I find symbols a lot clearer than text, simply because it scans as operator rather than text.

Comment: I'm also ^ a fan of ^. =) @randombet I prefer `ne` to `^=`, `!=` and `<>`.